# Multiple rows in single where ... like clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, sql-like

I am trying to create a search-form and am tring to search in multiple rows/ concatenated rows. Is there a way to use something like the following code:

```
$where = "
    WHERE
    (
        s.companyName,
        s.companyName || s.companyType,
        s.companyName || s.companyLocationType,
        s.companyLocationName,
        s.companyLocationName || s.companyLocationType
    ) LIKE (".$val.")
";
```

or:

```
$where = "
    WHERE
    (
        s.companyName
        OR s.companyName || s.companyType
        OR s.companyName || s.companyLocationType
        OR s.companyLocationName
        OR s.companyLocationName || s.companyLocationType
    ) LIKE (".$val.")
";
```

Or do i have to use it like that:

```
$where = "
    WHERE
        s.companyName LIKE (".$val.")
        OR s.companyName || s.companyType LIKE (".$val.")
        OR s.companyName || s.companyLocationType LIKE (".$val.")
        OR s.companyLocationName LIKE (".$val.")
        OR s.companyName || s.companyLocationType LIKE (".$val.")
";
```

Comment: Try something like the `ANY(array)` operator...

Comment: `ANY()` will not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE (".$val.") in (s.companyName | s.companyType,s.companyName | s.companyLocationType)
```

etc. will work if you're looking for an exact match rather than using LIKE.

Comment: this looks good and will be used on different occasions. But i will have to use LIKE in this case here as i will accept %/_-parameters for special searches too. And those dont work in in exact matches, do they? eg.: %c_b% finds facebook fpr example

Comment: In that case you might want to go with your last example, since you're comparing each different input to a pattern